# Are there "Goto"s in UNIX KSH scripts?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, ksh

Is there a way within a KSH to exit a case statement and go to a certain line for next execution with the code? Or are there goto labels you can use? Anything like this used instead of nesting tons of branching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no labels or goto.  However, you can exit a deeply-nested loop by passing a number to the "break" builtin: break 2 to exit two levels, break 3 to exit three levels, etc.

Comment: cool! thanks man. I was trying to read user input for a yes or no value, and if they entered no, I wanted to return to the original echo/input for the same case statement (i.e. Enter your name, $user is that correct (Y/N)?). But I think I may be structuring this wrong...either way I appreciate it! Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

While it always helps to post a simplified example of your problem (but that covers all contingencies you expect), given your comment reply to Mark Read, you can wrap the prompting for input into a while loop, like

```
while ${keepTrying:-true} ; do
   echo "enter Yes or No"
   read yOrN
   case "${yOrN} in
     [Yy]* ) 
       # do something 
       keepTrying=false
     ;;
     [Nn]* )
       # do something else
        keepTrying=false
    ;;
     * )
       echo "bad input"
     ;;
   esac
done

# continue with script
# ....
```

Also, I agree with Mark, no labels or gotos in ksh.

I hope this helps.

Comment: tidy.  No matter how long you I've been using ksh I still learn something new; your while ${keepTrying:-true} construct is excellent- thanks!

Comment: tnx, yes, I actually use this construct as appropriate!. Good luck to all!

Answer (score 0):

There is a bash goto implementation, if you want to adapt it to ksh (I haven't so far)

```
#!/bin/bash

function gowto
{
    label=$1
    # works in Linux bash, but barks in ksh
    cmd=$(sed -n "/#$label:/{:a;n;p;ba};" $0 | grep -v ':$')
    #
    eval "$cmd"
    exit
}

echo step 1

gowto skip

echo To be skippped

#skip:

echo Step 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I create the follwing script called GOTO.ksh:

```
#!/bin/ksh
#set -xv

OLD="$0"
NEW=/tmp/_$(basename "$0")
rm -f "$NEW"

grep "^#GOTO " "$OLD" | while read A B C
do
    [ -f "$NEW" ] || cp "$OLD" "$NEW"
    # printf "A=$A\nB=$B\nC=$C\n\n"
    sed -e "/^#GOTO $B/,/^#$B/s@^@\#. @" < "$NEW" > "$NEW"x && mv "$NEW"x "$NEW"
done
[ -f "$NEW" ] && { echo rm \"$NEW\" >> "$NEW" ;sync ; exec ksh "$NEW" $@; }
```

In the ksh script were the goto's are needed (for debugging) I invoke this as follows:

```
. ~/bin/GOTO.ksh
```

Now if one does want to skip ksh commands just put in:

```
#GOTO labelA
.... commands to be skipped ....
#labelA

.... commands to be executed ....

#GOTO labelB
.... commands to be skipped ...
#labelB
```

If there are #GOTO lines in the script, lines will be commented out, and the script will be written to /tmp (prepended with "_") and executed from there.